# Where to generate ressources into during Annotation processing in a maven workflow?

Tags: java, maven, annotation-processing

I have a maven project with several modules, i.e.

```
<module>backend</module>             <!-- provides annotations -->
<module>annotationProcessor</module> <!-- processes ann., generates files -->
<module>mainprog</module>            <!-- uses annotations/files -->
```

`backend` provides an annotation class `MyAnnotation` for annotating classes.

`mainprog` contains **`Mainprog.java`** which defines a class with a `@MyAnnotation` annotation. At runtime this class tries to load a file via  `getResourceAsStream("Mainprog.properties")` (which does not exist yet).

The `annotationProcessor` has a class `MyAnnotationProcessor` which *maven* executes and finds my annotations.

The processor **should create** the file `Mainprog.properties` from information gathered by the annotation processor.

I can not manage to put the properties file in a place where it is found when executing/testing Mainprog.

- Where should I generate the file to into, being in a maven workflow?
- How do I tell maven this file is used in tests or at runtime? Eventually
  is has to be packaged in the jar.

## Mainprog

```
package demo;
@MyAnnotation
public class Mainprog {
}
```

## Use the properties file

Currently I do it in the testing class, but later this will be in the class itself.

```
package demo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MainprogTest {

  Class testclass = Mainprog.class;

  @Test
  public void testPropertiesFile() throws IOException {
    String fn = testclass.getCanonicalName().replace('.', '/') + ".properties";
    System.err.println("loading: '"+fn+"'");
    InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(fn);
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(in);
    in.close();
  }
}
```

This currently runs as such:

```
loading: 'demo/Mainprog.properties'
Tests in error: 
   testPropertiesFile(demo.MainprogTest)
```

with a `NullPointerException`, because the stream returns `null`, i.e. does not exist.

Despite the file is there (but is it in the right place?):

```
towi@havaloc:~/git/project/mainprog$ find . -name Mainprog.properties 
./src/java/demo/Mainprog.properties
./target/classes/demo/Mainprog.properties
```

## Processor

```
package demo;

import com.github.javaparser.*;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.*;
import javax.annotation.processing.*;
import javax.lang.model.element.*;

@SupportedAnnotationTypes({"demo.MyAnnotation"})
public class MyAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

  @Override
  public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> elements, RoundEnvironment env) {
    for (TypeElement te : elements) {
      for (Element e : env.getElementsAnnotatedWith(te))
      {
        processAnnotation(e);
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  private void processAnnotation(Element elem) {
    final TypeElement classElem = (TypeElement) elem;
    ...
    final String prefix = System.getProperty("user.dir").endsWith("/"+"mainprog") ? "." : "mainprog";
    final String className = classElem.getQualifiedName().toString();
    String fileName = prefix + "/src/java/" + className.replace('.', '/') + ".java";
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    final CompilationUnit cu = JavaParser.parse(in);
    final CallGraph graph = ...
    generateInfoProperties(classElem, fileName, graph);
  }

  private void generateInfoProperties(TypeElement classElem, String inFilename, CallGraph graph) throws IOException {
    final File outFile = new File(inFilename
      .replace("/src/java/", "/src/java/") // <<< WHERE TO ???
      .replace(".java", ".properties"));
    outFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outFile, "UTF-8")) {
      final Properties ps = new Properties();
      graph.storeAsProperties(ps);
      ps.store(writer, inFilename);
      writer.close();
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, there is a lot of guesswork and "heuristics" going on when handling directory names. All that `System.getProperty("user.dir")` and `replace("/src/java/", "/src/java/")` is probably wrong, but what is better?

## maven

In Maven I have 4 poms, of course

- `pom.xml`
- `backend/pom.xml`
- `annotationProcessor/pom.xml`
- `mainprog/pom.xml`

Only one of seems to me contains anything of note, i.e., the execution of the annotation processor in `mainprog/pom.xml`:

```
<project>
 ....
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>annotationProcessor</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <build>
  <finalName>mainprog</finalName>
  <sourceDirectory>src/java</sourceDirectory>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>${basedir}/src/conf</directory>
      <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
    </resource>
    <resource>
      <directory>${basedir}/web</directory>
    </resource>
    <resource>
      <directory>${basedir}/src/java</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*.xml</include>
        <include>**/*.properties</include>
        <include>**/*.wsdl</include>
        <include>**/*.xsd</include>
      </includes>
    </resource>
  </resources>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <annotationProcessors>
        <annotationProcessor>demo.MyAnnotationProcessor
        </annotationProcessor>
      </annotationProcessors>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  ...
  </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

I thought by generating the file into `/src/java/` and then having `<resource><directory>${basedir}/src/java` and `<include>**/*.properties` is enough, but it does not seem so. Why is that?

Comment: `src/java` isn't Maven standard. It's rather [`src/main/java` or `src/test/java`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Answer (score 3):

Use the provided `Filer`, which can be obtained using `processingEnv.getFiler()`. If you create a source file using it, the compiler will compile it on the next round and you won't need to worry about configuring Maven to compile generated source files.